# How do I make a query return nothing when there are no conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql

Rather simple, I have a one to many / many to one relation and I'd like to query it.  However, I don't want any results returned when it isn't provided with any WHERE clause information.

In simpler terms, how do I make a query non-greedy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a where clause that is always false and append the condition you want supplied with OR:

```
select * from table where 1 = 0 OR (real conditions)
```