# How do I make a query return nothing when there are no conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine-1.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make a query return nothing when there are no conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824111/how-do-i-make-a-query-return-nothing-when-there-are-no-conditions)

If I have a query,I don't want any results returned when it isn't provided with any WHERE clause information.

In simpler terms, how do I make a query non-greedy?

Answer (score 1):

I think this would do the trick for you:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE 1=0
OR (some other criteria)
```